# Bootstrap pricing example - what am I doing wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

How do i reduce the space between the nav bar and the image?

(1) Need help for that (I am a newbie)

```html
<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3">
    <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal"></h5>
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">

      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    **<svg class="display-4">
      
      <image href="assets/img/picture.png" />
      </svg**>``
      <p class="lead">Quickly build an effective pricing table for your potential customers with this 
    Bootstrap example. It's built with default Bootstrap components and utilities with little 
    customization.</p>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Samantha92/8Ljy9xb5/2/

(2) Also, I need help, if I have 10 cards, I need them to show three each on the screen and maybe use carousel and move them off one at a time, with the center card being the one I can view or toggle.

[image: current view]
[image]

Comment: I have tried many variation to get the image in.. the most recent one is that i get the image in and it sits behind the cards..

Comment: 1) I am not sure what the issue is. If I replace the URL with the another image source, it shows fine and the text is shown below.

2) You can make use of inbuilt Bootstrap carousel: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ or use an external addon like https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: @m4n0it seems to be the size of the logo 

Hence i put in the following 

<image href="assets/img/Coolthings.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:250px;height:250px;"/>

However, How i decrease the space between the top bar and the logo? this seems like something i have to do with the css?

Comment: You need to edit this question and ask the 2nd one in another question.

Comment: Edit save. @m4n0 I want to know how i reduce the space between the nav bar at the top and the image.. seems like a css adjustment

Comment: You need to ask one question at a time. The other two needs to be in separate topics/questions.

Comment: You need to give a fix height and width to your svg element, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @devd how i go about doing that?

Comment: @tao need your help here..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o7zj6qeg/ , check this and let me know if this is all you wanted.

Comment: @devd with the height and stuff added to the css, my picture is not showing..But it surely address the issue i have

Comment: @devd do you have another solution?

Comment: .display-4{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  object-fit: contain;
} Replace your display-4 class with new one. If this works then fine otherwise you will have to provide a running example as the code editor link that you have shared , it has relative URL for image . So, unable to replicate your issue.

Comment: Devd i got it work by playing with the width and eight of the image.